# Two derivatives on a ring with two metrics?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, ring-theory, metric-spaces

In real analysis, the derivative can be defined by the limit formula:

$$D[f](x)v := \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t}$$

and we ask that as a function, $D[f] : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Sometimes, one wants to do analysis over a more general commutative ring with
a metric, or even more generally, a topological ring.  This is done for example by Bertram et al in "Differential calculus of general base fields and rings".

Here a continuous function $f : R \to R$ has a derivative when there is a 
continuous function $f^{[1]} : R \times R \times R \to R$ such that

$$f(x+tv)-f(x) = t\cdot f^{[1]}(x,v,t) \qquad (1)$$

The $f^{[1]}$ can be classically (over $\mathbb{R}$) described as

$$
  f^{[1]}(x,v,t) = 
    \begin{cases}
      \frac{f(x+tv) - f(x)}{t} & t \ne 0\\
      D[f](x)v & t = 0
    \end{cases}
  $$

But in general, as $R$ is not a field, an $f^{[1]}$ satisfying $(1)$ will not be defined as above.

When a continuous $f$ has an associated $f^{[1]}$ that
satisfies $(1)$, and that $f^{[1]}$ is linear in $v$, we may 
define its differential as

$$D[f](x)v := f^{[1]}(x,v,0)$$

Bertram makes an assumption that leads to $f^{[1]}$ being unique, and thus, is a "Fermat ring" (in the sense of Dubuc and Kock).  One aspect of uniqueness is that it makes the derivative well defined.  It also ensures that the collection of differentiable functions satisfies the chain rule, and other usual properties of differentiation.

But I am curious -- what if one changes the metric or the topology on the ring, but leaves the operations unchanged.  Is it possible for some fixed CRing $R$ to have two metrics and where the induced derivatives are different?

Link to Bertram et al: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0723086904800069

Dubuc and Kock: "On 1-form classifiers"  E. Dubuc and A. Kock.  Communications in Algebra.  Volume 12, Issue 12, 1984. pp 1471-1531.

-- Edits to clarify --

Comment: What do you mean by the difference quotient if $t$ is not a unit?

Comment: How embarrassing; as stated, what I have written is not well defined.  Thank you; I will update.  I meant for the difference quotient to be intuition, and for the equation of Bertram to be defining the difference quotient.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  For instance, let $R=\mathbb{Q}(t)$.  Any embedding $i:R\to\mathbb{R}$ induces a metric on $R$.  Now fix an embedding $i:R\to\mathbb{R}$ and a transcendental number $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus i(R)$ and define $f:R\to R$ by $f(x)=0$ if $i(x)<\alpha$ and $f(x)=1$ if $i(x)>\alpha$.  This $f$ is locally constant with respect to the metric induced by $i$, and thus is differentiable (with derivative identically $0$).

On the other hand, now let $j:R\to\mathbb{R}$ be the embedding that sends $t$ to $\alpha$.  The function $f$ is not even continuous with respect to the metric induced by $j$, because $f(q)=0$ for all rational numbers $q<\alpha$ and $f(q)=1$ for all rational numbers $q>\alpha$, and $t$ is in the closure of both of these sets.  So $f$ is differentiable with respect to the metric of $i$ but not with respect to the metric of $j$.